# Get the amount of posts on a current page

Tags: posts, loop, query-posts

I have loop and I want to get the amount of posts on a current page. So I try:

```
<?php $post_number = $wp_query->post_count; ?>
<?php echo($post_number) ; ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'post', get_post_format() );?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

but it doesn't work. I can't see result. So how can  I get amount of posts?

Comment: Can you please specify what do you mean by not working? Are you getting error? Wrong number? No result at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to output the post amounts

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post', 
  'showposts' => '10'
);
 $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
 // amount of posts per on the page
 $post_number = $wp_query->post_count;
 // amount of posts across the post pages
 $post_number2 = $wp_query->found_posts;
 echo $post_number.'<br />';
 echo $post_number2.'<br />';
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 php get_template_part( 'post', get_post_format() );
 php endwhile; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this `$count = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts`
This will show total found post on that page global query.